# VSTS agent not picking up deploy jobs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a private VSTS agent running on a Windows 2012 box that works fine to run builds. However it doesn't always pick up release jobs. The agent is enabled and in the correct pool, but when a release kicks off it says 'Waiting for an enabled agent. All possible agents are disabled.' The area below that message that usually shows possible agents is blank.

[image]

The only demand for that deploy is the built in DotNetFramework one:
[image]

And that exists on my agent
[image]

The weirder thing is that it did work for a few releases. Initially it wasn't picking them up, then I reinstalled the agent and it did pick them up, then it stopped again. This was all over the course of a few hours.

I read something about visual studio needing to be installed on deploy agents - is this the case? I don't have VS on that box but I don't get the issue on another box where VS is installed (although there's a plethora of other differences between those boxes too...).
Thanks.

Comment: There is newer agent (2.119.1) than 2.109.1, so try to download the build agent from VSTS, then configure it on that machine and check whether the issue persist.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have sorted it. I did try yesterday but I couldn't get it to connect - I had to add the VSTS_HTTP_PROXY to get it work. The older version was just picking up the system proxy but now it ignores that in favour of the env var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest build agent from VSTS and configure it, then queue build with this agent.